# Manage list permissions by app

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-online, office-365, autohosted

I need to manage permissions of `SPFolder` in a SharePoint document library from a SharePoint app published in the Office Store.

But looks like it's impossible, because:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142383(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142383%28v=office.15%29.aspx) :
Read, Write, Manage, **FullControl (in app)** corresponds to the default permission levels: Reader, Contributor, Designer, and **FULL CONTROL**.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288074.aspx :
Manage Permissions - Create and change permission levels on the Web site and assign permissions to users and groups. Included in these permission levels: **Full Control**

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220035(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220035%28v=office.15%29.aspx) :
5.9 Your app for SharePoint **cannot request full-control** permission.

So, we need FullControl permissions to manage permissions and we won't pass validation if we have FullControl.

Am I right? I can't change folder permissions from provider-hosted app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you cannot publish an app to the store that requests FullControl. However, you can upload any app to the App Catalog in your tenancy.

(Also, be aware that [Autohosted apps have been discontinued](http://blogs.office.com/2014/05/16/update-on-autohosted-apps-preview-program/). MSDN has guidance on [transitioning to Provider-hosted.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn722449%28v=office.15%29.aspx))

Comment: We develop an SP app and going to distribute it via Office Store. Looks like we won't be able to manage permissions in such case. It's a pity